# Iterative Comparison of raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a small max_min program I am writing in python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04. The code takes a user input inside an infinite loop that breaks on two conditions. I noticed that when I enter a number greater than 9 the program returns the incorrect results. What I want to do is for every time a user inputs a number, compare the number with the previous and get the maximum and minimum numbers ever entered from a user.

For example:

```
Please enter a number:
10
Max: 1, Min: 0, Count: 1
```

When the Max should be 10 not 1. Here is my code:

```
count = 0
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input('Please enter a number: ')
    # Kills the program
    if inp == 'done' : break
    if len(inp) < 1 : break

    # Gets the work done
    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input, please enter a number'
        continue
    # The numbers for count, largest and smallest
    count = count + 1
    # Gets largest number
    for i in inp:
        if largest is None or i > largest:
            largest = i
    print 'Largest',largest
    # Gets smallest number
    for i in inp:
        if smallest is None or i < smallest:
            smallest = i
    print 'Smallest', smallest

print 'Count:', count, 'Largest:', largest, 'Smallest:', smallest
```

Stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a string from `raw_input`,

```
>>> x = raw_input("Enter number: ")
Enter number: 10
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

Using the following code

```
for i in inp:
    if largest is None or i > largest:
        largest = i
print 'Largest',largest
# Gets smallest number
for i in inp:
    if smallest is None or i < smallest:
        smallest = i
print 'Smallest', smallest
```

You iterate over the string. In the first `for` loop, the loop runs for two values, `1` and `0`, and since `'1' > '0'`, largest gets `1`, similarly in the other loop, smallest gets `0`.

```
>>> '1' > '0'
True
```

If you're looking for a way to find the maximum and minimum number, may I suggest the following :

```
count = 0
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input('Please enter a number: ')
    # Kills the program
    if inp == 'done' : break
    if len(inp) < 1 : break

    # Gets the work done
    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input, please enter a number'
        continue
    # The numbers for count, largest and smallest
    count = count + 1
    # Gets largest number
    if largest is None or num > largest:  # Change 1
        largest = num
    print 'Largest',largest
    # Gets smallest number
    if smallest is None or num < smallest:  # Change 2
       smallest = num
    print 'Smallest', smallest

print 'Count:', count, 'Largest:', largest, 'Smallest:', smallest
```

Or you could just keep the numbers in a list and when `done` is typed, print out the `max()` and `min()` of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand what this is supposed to do, but you are iterating over the number and comparing 1 and than 0.

Shouldn't this

```
for i in inp:
    if largest is None or i > largest:
        largest = i
```

and the corresponding smallest one, be something like this instead?

```
if largest is None or inp > largest:
    largest = inp
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code loops over the string `'10'`, one individual character at a time; here the character `'1'` is larger than `'0'` because it's ASCII codepoint is higher. At no point do you actually build a  list of numbers.

Use a list to append numbers to:

```
numbers = []

while True:
    # get input

    numbers.append(num)
```

Then loop over `numbers` to calculate the min and max.

Bonus tip: set your `smallest` and `largest` names to `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` respectively, instead of `None`. This simplifies your tests for the minimum and maximum because these two values are guaranteed to be the largest and smallest numbers:

```
smallest = float('inf')
largest = float('-inf')

for i in numbers:
    if i > largest:
        largest = i
    if i < smallest:
        smallest = i
```

Note that you can do both tests in *one* loop.